# numeros distintos array java

Tags: java

El ejercicio consiste en lo siguiente:dados dos arrays de 5 posiciones,los llenamos con numeros aleatorios del 0 al 10 sin que se repitan(hasta ahi todo correcto) y después e un tercer array guardar los numeros del 1 al 10 que no se hayan guardado en ninguno de los 2 arrays.Ejemplo: en el array1(1,2,3,4,5) array2(1,4,2,3,8) en el tercer array(6,7,9,10).

este es el codigo que he intentado:

```
    int[] array1 = new int[5];
    int[] array2 = new int[array1.length];
    int numero = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        numero = rant.nextInt(10);
        if (repetidos(array1, numero) == false) {
            array1[i] = numero;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        numero = rant.nextInt(10);
        if (repetidos(array2, numero) == false) {
            array2[i] = numero;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("array2");
    for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(array2[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("array1");
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + array1[i]);
    }
    // guardar en un tercer array los numeros del 1 al 10 que no se hayan
    // guardado en ninguno de los 2 arrays
    int numero2 = 0;
    int numeroc = 10;// numero que se irá comparando a medida que vaya
                        // avanzando
    int posiciones = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
            if (array1[j] == numeroc || array2[i] == numeroc) {
                numeroc--;
            } else if (array1[j] != numeroc || array2[i] != numeroc) {
                posiciones++;
            }
        }
    }
    int[] array3 = new int[posiciones];// medida de el array definitivo

    for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < array3.length; b++) {

                if (array1[j] == numeroc || array2[i] == numeroc) {
                    numeroc--;
                } else if (array1[j] != numeroc || array2[i] != numeroc) {
                    array3[b] = numeroc;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("array3");
    for (int i = 0; i < array3.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(array3[i]);
    }

}

public static boolean repetidos(int[] array, int numero) {

    boolean repetido = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == numero) {
            repetido = true;

        }
    }
    return repetido;
```

y el output es el siguiente:
array2
46810array1
 9 3 1 0 2array3
10101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010

cuál es el fallo?en qué he fallado exactamente?hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo mas facil.  Ya tienes una funcion que te dice si un elemento esta en un array, solo debes usarla asi:

```
int b = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if(!repetidos(array1, i) && !repetidos(array2, i) {
     array3[b] = i;
     b++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu código tiene un problema.

**El bucle que utilizas para rellenar array1 y array2** con números aleatorios tiene un fallo ya que se **deja posiciones sin llenar (a cero)** cuando se da el caso que un número está repetido. Una solución es la siguiente:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length;) {
        numero = rant.nextInt(10);
        if (arrayContieneNumero(array1, numero) == false) {
            array1[i] = numero;
            i++;
        }
    }
```

**Solo debes incrementar la variable de control cuando un numero no este repetido**. Es por eso que la saco fuera.

Por otro lado, **la solución que propone alanfcm me parece correcta**.

Saludos, David.